# Automate OAuth in Dropbox API - Clicking the submit button to login

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, splinter

I'm trying to login to Dropbox via the official Dropbox API and upload a file to my Dropbox.

The code doesn't seem te click on the submit button in order to login to Dropbox. The code does not stop it just hangs or freezes. I don't get an error so there is no traceback.

What's strange is that when I comment out either the filling of the email or password (or both), clicking the submit button works.

I do not want to manually visit the Dropbox authentication link and click the Allow button. So I'm trying to automate that task by using a tool ([Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/)) that let's me automate browser actions.

For my code I'm using [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) and as browser type I'm using [PhantomJS](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/drivers/phantomjs.html)

Here's the code:

```
from splinter import *
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# Initiate Dropbox API
APP_KEY = '###'
APP_SECRET = '###'
ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'
sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
emailDropbox = '###'
passwordDropbox = '###'

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

urlDropbox = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)

# Start Splinter login code
# Assumes you are not logged in to Dropbox

# Target url
print 'Target url: ', urlDropbox

browser = Browser('phantomjs')
print 'Starting browser'
print 'Visiting url'
browser.visit(urlDropbox)

# Email form
print 'Is the email form present? ', browser.is_element_present_by_id('login_email')
print 'Fill email form'
browser.find_by_id('login_email').first.fill(emailDropbox)

# Password form
print 'Is the password form present? ', browser.is_element_present_by_id('login_password')
print 'Fill password form'
browser.find_by_id('login_password').first.fill(passwordDropbox)

# Login submit button
print 'Is the submit button present?', browser.is_element_present_by_name('login_submit_dummy')

# Click submit button
print 'Attempting to click the submit button in order to login'
browser.find_by_name('login_submit_dummy').first.click()
print 'Submit button successfully clicked'

# Allow connection with Dropbox
print 'Is the "Allow" button present?', browser.is_element_present_by_id('allow_access')
browser.find_by_id('allow_access').click()
print 'The "Allow" button is successfully clicked'

# Quit the browser
browser.quit()

# The rest of the Dropbox code
# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)

client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
print "linked account:", client.account_info()

f = open('working-draft.txt')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
print "uploaded:", response
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong and how I could fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to work by pausing for 5 seconds before clicking using `time.sleep(5)`.

Here's the working code:

```
from splinter import *
from dropbox import rest, session
from dropbox import client as dbclient
import time

# Dropbox API
APP_KEY = '###'
APP_SECRET = '###'
ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'
sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
emailDropbox = '###'
passwordDropbox = '###'

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

urlDropbox = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)

def phantomjsOAuth():
    # Target url
    print 'Target url: ', urlDropbox

    browser = Browser('phantomjs')
    print 'Starting phantomjs browser'
    print 'Visiting url'
    browser.visit(urlDropbox)

    # Email form
    print 'Is the email form present? ', browser.is_element_present_by_id('login_email')
    print 'Filling email form'
    browser.find_by_id('email-field').first.find_by_id('login_email').first.fill(emailDropbox)
    print 'Email form successfully filled'

    # Password form
    print 'Is the password form present? ', browser.is_element_present_by_id('login_password')
    print 'Filling password form'
    browser.find_by_id('login_password').first.fill(passwordDropbox)
    print 'Password form successfully filled'

    # Find login submit button
    print 'Is the "Submit" button present?', browser.is_element_present_by_name('login_submit_dummy')
    submitButton = browser.is_element_present_by_name('login_submit_dummy')

    if submitButton == True:
        print 'Pausing for 5 seconds to avoid clicking errors'
        time.sleep(5)
        print 'Attempting to click the "Submit" button in order to login'
        browser.find_by_name('login_submit_dummy').first.click()
        print '"Submit" button successfully clicked'

        # Allow connection with Dropbox
        print 'Is the "Allow" button present?', browser.is_element_present_by_css('.freshbutton-blue')
        allowButton = browser.is_element_present_by_css('.freshbutton-blue')

        if allowButton == True:
            print 'The "Allow" button is present, attempting to click..'
            browser.find_by_css('.freshbutton-blue').click()
            print 'The "Allow" button is successfully clicked, access to Dropbox is granted.'

            browser.quit()

            dropboxCode()

        else:
            print 'The "Allow" button is not present, quitting.'
            browser.quit()

    else:
        print 'The "Submit" button was not present, quitting.'
        browser.quit()

def dropboxCode():
    # The rest of the Dropbox code
    # This will fail if 'Allow' wasn't clicked
    access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)

    client = dbclient.DropboxClient(sess)
    print "linked account:", client.account_info()

    f = open('dropbox_api_test_file.txt')
    response = client.put_file('/Python/Apps/###/Orders/dropbox_api_test_file.txt', f)
    print "uploaded:", response
    sess.unlink()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    phantomjsOAuth()
```